# Images not displaying on other iOS devices

Tags: ios, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am having issues displaying images in my FlatList on other iPhones/iOS devices or iOS simulator. I can view the images on my iPhone but they do not show on other devices. I'm aware that the images are locally stored on my phone, and so I believe this may be the reason why I can see the images on my phone and not on others.

On the simulator the error below appears on initial render and the screen appears blank with no images:

Task orphaned for request <NSMutableURLRequest: 0x600...>

[image]

I am using react-native-image-crop-picker to get the pictures and and Firebase real-time database to store the images.

How do I view the images on other devices? Can someone please assist? I am fairly new to React Native. Please do let me know if you require more info.

Answer (score 0):

Using react-native-image-crop-picker, you need to save the whole image on your database or on your storage, you can't save tha local path and pretending that other phone will see that image.

You have two possibility, the first one is to use firebase storage. When react-native-image-crop-picker give you the path, you can use that path to upload the image on firebase storage and save the downloadUrl on your document. Then you can use that downloadUrl to show the image on other phone.

The second one is to use the incluseBase64 prop on react-native-image-crop-picker and use that base64 string to show the image and save it to your database.